# How to access SharedPreference on run time service?

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

I know how to store SharedPreference and how to access them.
On some event of my application I will store time and string to sharedPreference.
On same time depending on that time I'm setting broadcast receiver.

When that time appear my app may be open or may not be.
onReceive method of service I'm redirecting user to some activity which shows this time and string to user.

But when that time appear how can access to that SharedPreference?

```
private static SharedPreferences sharedPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

As SharedPreference stored depending on Context but at run time my application may not be open.
So how can I access to this SharedPreference at runtime on another activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During any runtime of your app atleast one component is running it can be `Service`, `BroadCastreceiver` or `Activity` .. All of these component have a Context attached to them. 
In case of `Activity` or `Service` you can directly is `ClassName.this` in place of `Context` because these two classes derived from `ContextWrapper`.

In case of `BroadcastReceiver` you get context as parameter in `#onReceive` ..

```
class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         SharedPreferences sharedPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }
}
```

For a service you can directly use `this` .

```
class MyService extends Service {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreference;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sharedPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```